# How to find the coeffecients(a,b,c,d) of a planar polygon

Tags: 3d, geometry, polygon, plane

Given the normal of the plane,Centroid of the plane,the bais vectors,and some(>4) points on the plane , i want to find out the co-effecients(a,b,c,d) of the planar polygon.
Is there a better way than substitute  points in the plane equation ax + by + cz + d = 0.

Thanks,
Harsha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation will be

```
n_x x + n_y y + n_z z + d = 0
```

where `N[n_x, n_y, n_z]` is the normal vector.  Then you can substitute any point `B(b_x, b_y, b_z)` known to be on the plane to solve for `d`,

```
d = -( n_x b_x + n_y b_y + n_z b_z )
```

Why does this work?  Let `P(x,y,z)` be an arbitrary point in the plane. Then the vector `P-B` must be parallel to the plane and perpendicular to its normal. The dot product of perpendiculars is zero.  Consequently,

```
N dot (P -  B) = (N dot P - N dot B) 
    = n_x x + n_y y + n_z z - (n_x b_x + n_y b_y + n_z b_z) = 0
```

In the last line you can recognize

```
a = n_x   b = n_y    c = n_z   d = -(n_x b_x + n_y b_y + n_z b_z)
```

as already stated.

Comment: Hey,one more doubt.. can we use the centroid as a point on the plane.